# Ruby On Rails: how to extract nested parameters from POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to grab the values for the keys `id` and `quantity` from the `params` hash submitted with a POST form.

The parameters:

```
params
# => {...
     "form"=>
      {"name"=>"joe",
       "date_sent"=>"09/28/2016",
       "emp_num"=>"54552452",
       "items_attributes"=>{"1474227471986"=>{"id"=>"3", "quantity"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1474227474062"=>{"id"=>"4", "quantity"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false"}},
       "comments"=>"af",
       "accepted"=>"false"},
     "commit"=>"Submit",
     "m"=>"true"}
```

Comment: What code do you have?  Nested hashes are a pretty basic feature of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following way you can grab **id** and **quantity** of all nested item attributes.

```
params['form']['items_attributes'].values.collect { |value| { id: value['id'], quantity: value['quantity'] } }
```

Output:

```
[ {:id => 3, :quantity => 5 }, { :id => 4, :quantity => 3 } ]
```

Comment: do I really need 'key' for the each loop? I am not using it.

Comment: @MarcosIcaza I have updated my answer for only using values.

Comment: I get a "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" when I remove key.

Comment: Maybe :id and :quantity is the key

Comment: @MarcosIcaza paste your code in comment. are you using my updated code? We only need to iterate over values.

Comment: I did exactly what you did, but when I remove key it gives me an error.

Comment: I have tested my code in rails console, its perfectly working, may be you are doing any silly mistake. just paste your code.

Comment: items = params['form']['items_attributes'].collect { |value| { id: value['id'], quantity: value['quantity'] } }
      
puts items

Comment: @MarcosIcaza you are missing `.values`, compare your code with answer.

Comment: You were right. One last question: How do you grab now the values from the hash table? I did: items = params['form']['items_attributes'].values.collect { |value| { id: value['id'], quantity: value['quantity'] } } and then I try items[:id] and it gives me TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: @myhouse you need to iterate `items` like, `items.each { |item| puts item[:id] }`